# Identificar extensão instalada no google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google, google-chrome-extensão

Como consigo identificar que o Google Chrome do usuário que esta acessando meu site tem determinada extensão instalada.
Por ex, se tem a extensão da Glogo.com/Itau, etc..

Preciso verificar isso para mostrar ou não um banner para instalação da extensão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe na documentação do Chrome uma forma nativa de verificar, segue o link

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

Answer (score 7):

Toda extensão possui um ID e, quando instaladas, um manifesto que fica no computador do usuário.

Basta acessar o seguinte endereço:

```
chrome-extension://ID/manifest.json
<!-- Substitua o "ID" acima pelo da sua aplicação. -->
<!-- Note que ID é um texto bem longo e aleatório, não um número. -->
```

Você pode fazer isso com ajax, por exemplo. Se der erro 404 é porque a extensão não está instalada.

Uma tentativa bem simples de acessar o endereço via Ajax pode ser feita assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "chrome-extension://idnljhnpjegfbcohjhdnhjlnfnffmbnf/manifest.json"
    // A extensão acima é o módulo de proteção do Santander.
});
```

Como você é o autor de sua extensão, fica a seu cargo determinar seu ID. Para testar isso com extensões que você não desenvolveu, vou deixar uma dica: vá em configurações -> extensões e procure os ID's das extensões no código fonte da página ;) Daí é só usar a forma acima para testar com as extensões que você já tem na sua máquina.

Comment: Para poder acessar via ajax os recursos da extensao precisa dar acesso ao arquivo no manifest:

"web_accessible_resources": [
    "manifest.json"
  ],